# How to handle GooglePlayServicesRepairableException and GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I read the official docs and it confuses me. What is difference between 
`GooglePlayServicesRepairableException` and `GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException`. When they are thrown? How to handle these errors? How to show a dialog to user, where he can enable/update/install the services. e.t.c.

```
private void startLocationPicker() {
        try {
            new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder().build(this);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {

        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the [GooglePlayServicesRepairableException docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesRepairableException):

> GooglePlayServicesRepairableExceptions are special instances of [UserRecoverableException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/UserRecoverableException.html)s which are thrown when Google Play Services is not installed, up-to-date, or enabled. In these cases, client code can use [getConnectionStatusCode()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesRepairableException.html#getConnectionStatusCode()) in conjunction with [getErrorDialog(android.app.Activity, int, int)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#getErrorDialog(android.app.Activity,%20int,%20int)) to provide users with a localized Dialog that will allow users to install, update, or otherwise enable Google Play services.

[GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException) also has an error code which can be used with `getErrorDialog()`, although I'd encourage you to look over all of the methods available in [GoogleApiAvailability](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability).