# google play services problem in flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, google-play-services

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16697): com.example.try_1 requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16697): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9
W/Firestore(16697): (24.7.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
```

this  is what prints me in the terminal of android studio when i wanted to display the data in firestore

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about your Emulator that does not support Google Play or unsigned. Maybe you can try another emulator which includes Google Play Services.

You may go and create a new virtual device. It should be supporting Google Play Service.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
```

It *clearly* indicates that you are missing [Google Play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview).

From [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services):

> Some Firebase Android SDKs depend on Google Play services, which means they will only run on devices and emulators with Google Play services installed.

---

If you are using AVD manager, you can install a phone that says **Google Play** (*not* Google API) next to it:

[image]

##### See also

- [Is Google Play Store supported in avd emulators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593738/is-google-play-store-supported-in-avd-emulators)
- [How to handle GooglePlayServicesRepairableException and GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448163/how-to-handle-googleplayservicesrepairableexception-and-googleplayservicesnotava)
- [How to use Firebase API on Android without the Google Play Service dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365560/how-to-use-firebase-api-on-android-without-the-google-play-service-dependency)